# How to order a post type by another post type field (acf)

Tags: wordpress

I have a post type named 'product' which i added a custom field named 'partner'. I have another post type named 'partners' where each 'partner' post has custom field 'is_top_partner'.

The aim is to query post type product and order by top partner, show top partners products shows on top of results. I have pagination and want all to partner before.

```
// Query the product post type
$args = array('post_type' => 'product');
$products = new Wp_Query($args);

// Query the partners post type
$argsPartners = array('post_type' => 'partners');
$partners = new Wp_Query($args);

if($products->have_posts()) {
    while($products->have_posts()) : 
        $products->the_post():
        $partner = get_field('partner', $product->ID);
        // ... what should i do here ? 
    endwhile;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: One question: does the custom field `partner` of `product` allow multi-select, or can there only be one partner per product?

Comment: Hi, thank you, just one partner per product